# Refresh a single item in a WPF ItemCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that is bound to some XML data.

When I make changes in the XML data, the DataGrid does not refresh to reflect those changes.

My "simple" way of fixing this is to call MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh() every time I make a change.

However, this is laggy and seems pretty inefficient.

How can I refresh just a *single* row, rather than the entire data grid? I have easy access to the DataGridRow as well as the XmlElement that is changed, but I just don't know what function to call.

Been stuck on this problem for 3-4 hours now and have tried dozens of solutions, but just can't get it to work.

Below is relevant code.

A) Defining the style.

```
    <!-- Field Value Style -->
    <local:FieldValueConverter x:Key="FieldValueConverter"/>
    <local:Node x:Key="Node"/>
    <Style x:Key="fieldValueStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource FieldValueConverter}}"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
```

B) Defining the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FieldPanelDataGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ObjectPanelListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        CanUserResizeRows="False"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
        Visibility="Visible"
        SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="FieldCell_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="FieldCell_PreviewMouseLeftButonDown"></EventSetter>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="FieldCell_PreviewKeyDown"></EventSetter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FieldName" Header="Name" CanUserSort="False" ElementStyle="{StaticResource fieldNameStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FieldValue" Header="Value" Width="*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource fieldValueStyle}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: can you remove the changed XmlElement from the source collection and then re-insert it at the same position? it could work..

Comment: Probably start by showing us your code that reads the XML and populates the datagrid. Also, are the changes to the XML (file) external to the application? If so, maybe you can hook up a filesystemwatcher to watch your xml file, and update your data grid accordingly.

Comment: @h.alex: good thought. I get an error along the lines of "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead" though. And failedprogramming: I updated the original post with some code. The changes are within the application.

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22763268/1144090) helps.

Comment: @h.alex: I checked out the post; how would the "List" and "ObservableCollection" relate to my problem? Would I implement a custom DataGrid type, or a custom DatGridRow type?

Comment: I don't know, you're not showing the code which is manipulating the items list, but my guess is you are making the same error of the question I linked to.

Comment: All I do is change the InnerXML of XMLElements, and call Document.Save().

Comment: Please show the xaml defining the datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use an ObservableCollection as ItemSource and the entries in the ObservableCollection have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Then you have the benefit if the rows change, the ObservableCollection will tell that your UI and it will update.

Example:

Your entry class:

```
public class MyXmlObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string fieldName;

    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return fieldName; }
        set
        {
            fieldName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FieldName");
        }
    }

    NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Your code for the UserControl (ViewModel, Controller or Code behind):

```
public ObservableCollection<MyXmlObject> MyCollection { get; set; }
```

And as I mentioned in your xaml you simply bind the collection to the ItemsSource

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" .../>
```

Now only the items beeing changed get updated.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but when I change my DataGrid's ItemSource from {Binding} to {Binding MyCollection} all my items disappear.

Comment: It depends on your UserControls DataContext. You have to put the Collection to the Class that represents the UserControls DataContext. For instance, if it is the code behind of your UserControl itself try to set __DataContext = this;__

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work, because I am already setting the DataContext in the XAML to "{Binding ElementName=ObjectPanelListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"